# How come <<<_END does not work

Tags: php

I am trying to learn php from 'learning php MySQL & Javascript' by Robin Nixon.

In it he explains how the following code should output literally (with line endings and whitespace) preserved. But it outputs everything on one line. Why is that?

```
$author = "Alfred E Newman";
echo <<<_END

This is a headline

This is the first line
This is the second
- Written by $author.
_END;
```

Comment: I don't know the answer unfortunately, but a `\n` might be of some assist. (You'll need to use double quotes around it though)

Comment: Thanks, yes I know I could use the new line syntax, but am trying to figure out why his example does not work

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/6NIEt

Comment: Yes, I see, I wonder if it may be my php installation then.

Comment: @Jelmar Don't forget to put a check by the best answer.  It give both you and the answerer points.

Answer (score 5):

It most likely is outputting everything on it's "own line", however, if this is on a HTML page, your line breaks may not be preserved. Wrap everything in `<pre>` to keep all white space.

Example:

```
echo <<<_END
<pre>
This is a headline

This is the first line
This is the second
- Written by $author.
</pre>
_END;
```

To have proper mark-up, you should wrap elements in their respective containers, such as:

```
echo <<<_END
<h2>This is a headline</h2>

<p>This is the first line</p>
<p>This is the second</p>
<p>- Written by $author.</p>
_END;
```

The above example will break up your content into sections.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely output it on a HTML document. You'll have to use `nl2br()` to convert `\n` linebreaks in `<br />` HTML linebreaks.

Comment: Thanks, my question is answered:-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this in a browser or on a command line?

If you're looking at your browser:

The browser will not honor newlines like a command-line would; it squishes them all together.

if you view the page source of the generated page you will see that it is indeed outputting it as you wanted.

Comment: You are right. Page source DOES show it. Okay then, the author recommends working in an IDE. But I like the real world experience. Much better learning. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with the same example in Learning PHP, MySQL, JavaScript & CSS by Robin Nixon. It turned out that I had some white space after the semicolon of _END;

I know this is a couple years old, but in case someone else is having an issue with this example.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need "_END" that's just an example of the book.
Only <<< is needed to be remembered.
So:

```
echo <<<something
lorem ipsum
lorem lorem
ipsum ipsum
something;
```

Will work as well.

As for why it doesn't seem to work well, browsers wont render it but viewing source code will show it as expected.